# how to write IsNull() in linq?

Tags: sql, linq, isnull

I want to write below query in linq.please help me.

```
SELECT ISNULL(userfirstname, '')userfirstname, useremail, usermobile FROM [user] 
WHERE useremail='eeeee@gmail.com'
```

Comment: since you are in c# side now,. you can just easily compare it to `null`

Comment: @PavanReddy, should there be `ISNULL(userfirstname, ''),userlastname` etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.user.Where(u => u.useremail == "eeeee@gmail.com").
        Select(u => u.userfirstname ?? string.Empty);
```

This filters for your specified email and then projects the result by returning `userfirtname` or an empty string if `userfirstname` is `null`.

---

For your updated question:

```
db.user.Where(u => u.useremail == "eeeee@gmail.com").
        Select(u => new { 
             userfirstname = u.userfirstname ?? string.Empty,
             useremail = u.useremail,
             usermobile = u.usermobile});
```

This returns a sequence of instances of an anonymous type containing your values. You can create a data class for that too if you want:

```
public class MyUser
{
    public string userfirstname { get; set; }
    public string useremail { get; set; }
    public string usermobile { get; set; }
}

db.user.Where(u => u.useremail == "eeeee@gmail.com").
        Select(u => new MyUser { 
             userfirstname = u.userfirstname ?? string.Empty,
             useremail = u.useremail,
             usermobile = u.usermobile});
```

Comment: Your answer is better

Comment: @PavanReddy updated my answer (though it's not so good to change your requirements after you got answers). Note that your question currently does not contain valid SQL: what's that with the second `userfirstname` without a separating comma?

Comment: @RenéVogt sorry some mistake.actually I want if username is null it returns empty.

Comment: @RenéVogt Thank you for reply.its help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
user.Where(x => x.useremail == "eeeee@gmail.com").Select(x => new {x.userfirstname ?? string.Empty, x.userlastname, x.useremail, x.usermobile})
```

you generate an anonymous type at the end